# QOpenGLWidget stops repainting on update()

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.7

I have a custom QDialog which contains a hierarchy with 4 separate instances of `QOpenGLWidget`.

Each of these `QOpenGLWidget`'s has its own GL context, and renders a different scene.

I have a loop which calls `update()` (the recommended method for repainting them) on each `QOpenGLWidget` regularly (the focused one more regularly, however I think this is irrelevant to the problem).

My problem is that eventually after random amounts of time (sometime it happens quickly, other times it won't happen for 10+ mins), one or more `QOpenGLWidget`'s will stop repainting when `update()` is called.

I have however noticed that resizing the stalled `QOpenGLWidget` causes a single repaint event to be triggered.

I can see with the debugger that `update()` is being called on all the `QOpenGLWidget`'s, but this is never triggering `paintGL()` (the repaint method) for the stalled widgets. and that `updatesEnabled()` always returns true, regardless of wether `update()` is triggering repaints or not. QT also isn't printing any errors or warnings to console.

The dialog containing these widgets is running in a separate thread to the one that triggers `update()`, so I can't call `repaint()` directly (without writing my own event loop).

Adding `QApplication::sync()` to the method that triggers `update()` doesn't make a difference either.

I'm inclined to think it occurs more when there's less ram available, however less ram is in the order of 800mb, and the application uses significantly less than that. So my gut is probably wrong.

I'm not a big user of QT, so I'm not too sure where to go from here debugging the issue further, any suggestions would be welcome. Given the reproducibility of the error involves waiting an unknown length of time and a more complex and multi-threaded project, can't imagine there would be much benefit to me attempting to reproduce the bug with a small snippet of code.

---

### Update:

Just ran into exactly the same issue when calling `update()` on a `QGraphicsScene`, however it was occurring after only a couple of updates every time.

Found [this](http://www.qtforum.org/article/19433/repainting-a-qgraphicsview-after-the-scene-is-modified.html?s=cc877db2468888894828548dd9fc84abffc5b6af#post80079) suggestion to instead update the viewport with `viewport()->update()` and it appears to have fixed the problem.

`QOpenGLWidget` however doesn't have a viewport to update in the same way.