# QopenGLWidget paintGL is only triggered by resizeGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es, qt5

I have implemented my own QOpenGLWidget class.
I use update() when a new video frame is arrived, or resizeGL is called.

At the beginning, the video frame is showing fine by paintGL. But after some time(<3min), paintGL is only triggered by resizeGL, not by update() from new video frames.

I find others are encountering the same problem. But no solutions have been posted.
[QOpenGLWidget only updates when resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907845/qopenglwidget-only-updates-when-resized)

[How can QOpenGLWidget update not result in paintGL events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748991/how-can-qopenglwidget-update-not-result-in-paintgl-events)

[QOpenGLWidget stops repainting on update()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865672/qopenglwidget-stops-repainting-on-update?rq=1)

Update:
When I only render one QOpenGLWidget, everything is fine. But when two or more,
the bigger one will soon freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the answer.

I have to invoke qt's update() method in the main thread. You can achieve it by QT's sig-slot.

I just wonder, why update() have to be invoked in main thread, is it a QT bug?

Comment: All kind of GUI work has to be done in the main thread in order to work properly. So that's probably no Qt Bug.